# jQuery Lazy onError - set onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading

I'm using jQuery Lazy: http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/

I want to have one onclick function for my image element when it is loaded successfully, and a different onclick function when there is an error. Unfortunately, neither of these onclick functions seems to work. In my .lazy call I set the parameters:

```
afterLoad: function ( element )
        {
            element.onclick = function()
            {
                alert( "ya" );
            };
        }

onError: function( element )
        {
            element.onclick = function()
            {
                alert( "err" );
            };
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`element` is a jQuery object, not a DOM element.

Try:

```
element.on('click', function () {
    alert('ya!');
});
```

To go with your solution, you would have to access the DOM node within the wrapper, but do not do this as you would deafeat the purpose of using jQuery.

```
element[0].onclick = function () {
};
```

Comment: Thanks! Well, that solved part of the problem, but now, even images that have an error still alert "ya" when clicked. I can confirm that the onError function is being applied to the image object that has an error, but it seems that the "err" onclick function is going unnoticed.

Comment: Could you setup a jsfiddle to demonstrate the issue? I have never used the plugin, but as far I can see in their examples, the `afterLoad` handler shouldn't get called when there's an error.

Comment: In my onError I changed the src of element to be an 'error image', so when that image loaded, then the afterLoad would be called for it. If I don't do that, then I don't get the extra afterLoad call. However, I still can't get the onclick event to work for onError images ... I'll make a work around ..

Comment: @Lebowski156 Great! By the way, if you setup a fiddle we can probably help you to find what's wrong.